# Serverless PHP on AWS with bref deployment error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, serverless, bref

I recently discovered what promises to be the holy grail of PHP development on AWS Lambda. It's a tool called "bref" which simplifies the way PHP apps are deployed to the cloud.

The online documentation has simple and clear instructions to follow here:
https://bref.sh/docs/first-steps.html

Unfortunately, I get the following error when deploying (sls deploy):

```
Serverless plugin "./vendor/bref/bref" initialization errored: Cannot find module './vendor/bref/bref'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/utils/autocomplete.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless
```

This error appears to say that there are some missing npm packages but the documentation on the bref website does not address any additional packages to be installed. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already had PHP version 7.3 installed. The problem was having an old version of Serverless Framework. But in order for me to upgrade my version of Serverless, I had to first upgrade NPM as well.

```
npm i -g npm
```

Then I could upgrade Serverless Framework:

```
npm install -g serverless@latest
```